# How do define a rule only if a precondition is true?

Tags: prolog

I try to assign IP addresses to hosts with `host_ip`. But I want that any IP address defined should fulfill some preconditions. First the address octets should not exceed the valid range and second I want only addresses from the class A network 10.0.0.0/8.

I tried to use `assertz` but it does not work as expected:

```
byte(X) :- integer(X), X >= 0, X =< 255.
ip(A, B, C, D) :- byte(A), byte(B), byte(C), byte(D).

valid_ip(A, B, C, D) :-
    ip(A, B, C, D),
    A = 10.

add_host(Name, A, B, C, D) :-
    valid_ip(A, B, C, D),
    assertz(host_ip(Name, A, B, C, D)).

add_host(host1, 10, 0, 0, 1).
add_host(host2, 11, 0, 0, 1).
```

The rule `valid_ip` works as expected:

```
?- valid_ip(1,2,3,4).
false.

?- valid_ip(10,2,3,4).
true.

?- valid_ip(1000,2,3,4).
false.
```

But I can not query the IP address of `host1`.

```
?- host_ip(host1, X).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: host_ip/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

What is wrong with my `assertz` usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two independent issues:

## Facts vs. directives

Your program currently simply contains **facts** of the form `add_host/5`.

You can query these facts with:

```
?- add_host(H, A, B, C, D).
H = host1,
A = 10,
B = C, C = 0,
D = 1 ;
H = host2,
A = 11,
B = C, C = 0,
D = 1.
```

What you **meant** is to run the **goal** `add_host/5` after loading the file, and you can do this for example with the `initialization/1` **directive**:

```
:- initialization add_host(host1, 10, 0, 0, 1).
:- initialization add_host(host2, 11, 0, 0, 1).
```

Note that when loading this file, you will get a warning similar to:

```
Initialization goal failed
```

You can use `ignore/1` around the goal to ignore the failure.

## Correct arity

Still, even if you fix this and load the file, you get:

```
?- host_ip(H, IP).
ERROR: Undefined procedure: host_ip/2
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         host_ip/5
```

In this case, the error message tells you what is wrong: You are asserting facts of the form `host_ip/5`, and they are there as expected:

```
?- host_ip(H, A, B, C, D).
H = host1,
A = 10,
B = C, C = 0,
D = 1.
```

To keep the numbers together, consider using for example `assertz(host_ip(Host,ip(A,B,C,D))`, asserting facts of the form `host_ip/2`, where the second argument denotes the IP using a suitable **compound term**.

Answer (score 2):

The line:  `assertz(host_ip(Name, A, B, C, D)).`  adds the clause `host_ip(Name,A,B,C,D)` in Prolog database. This definition is a predicate host_ip with five arguments  but when you query  `host_ip(host1, X).` you ask for a predicate host_ip that has two arguments.

You could simply concatenate the A,B,C,D in one atom like:

```
add_host(Name, A, B, C, D) :-
    valid_ip(A, B, C, D),
    atom_concat(A,B,X),
    atom_concat(X,C,Y),
    atom_concat(Y,D,Z),
    assertz(host_ip(Name, Z)).
```